# How can i reach the 'dates' saved in my database with mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

[So basically that is what my datatable looks like, i have 2 database entries one as import and the other one with import vorfälle][1]

[Here you can see that my imports are identified by an id and what i want is that the importdate is given as an output on my datatable][2]

[In this database my imports are identified by the import_id and it is declared if it is a change or an error as: vorfall][3]

My main problem is that i cannot reach the 'dates' so in my datatable it always gives me the 01.01.1970 01:00:00 Uhr as 'Importzeitpunkt' and 'Erstellung des SAP-Exports'.

```
  // Import-Tabelle
        $sqlres = $this->ctb->sql->query('SELECT * FROM ' . $this->ctb->config->dbprefix . 'asp WHERE import="prices" ORDER BY importDate DESC');
        if ($sqlres->num_rows < 1) {
            $this->ctb->tpl->assign('TABLEROWS', '<tr><td colspan="2" class="text-center">bisher wurden keine Preise importiert</td></tr>');
        } else {
            $i = 0;
            while ($import = $sqlres->fetch_assoc()) {
                $i++;
                $this->ctb->tpl->assign('ROWCLASS', ($i == 1 && $importReturn == "success") ? 'success' : '');
                ** THATS WHERE I TRY TO GET MY IMPORTDATE OUT OF MY DATABASE **
                $this->ctb->tpl->assign('DATUMZEIT', date('d.m.Y H:i:s', strtotime(])).' Uhr');
                $this->ctb->tpl->assign('FILEDATE', date('d.m.Y H:i:s', strtotime'])).' Uhr');


                $sqlres_changes = $this->ctb->sql->query('SELECT id'
                        . 'FROM ' . $this->ctb->config->dbprefix . 'iv '
                        . 'LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM ' . $this->ctb->config->dbprefix . 'aussch WHERE deleted=false) t '
                        . 'ON t.id = iv.teil_id WHERE iv.vorfall = "change" AND iv.import_id=' . $import['id']);
                if ($sqlres_changes->num_rows < 1) {
                    $this->ctb->tpl->assign('CHANGES', 'keine');
                } else {
                    $changelinks = array();
                    while ($changes = $sqlres_changes->fetch_assoc()) {
                        $changelinks[] = "<a href='?module=auss=$changes[id]' data-toggle='tooltip' data-placement='bottom' title='$changes[bezeichnung]'>$changes[nummer]</a>";
                    }
                    $this->ctb->tpl->assign('CHANGES', implode(', ', $changelinks));
                }


                $sqlres_errors = $this->ctb->sql->query('SELECT t.id, t.nummer, t.bezeichnung '
                        . 'FROM ' . $this->ctb->config->dbprefix . ' iv '
                        . 'LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM ' . $this->ctb->config->dbprefix . 'WHERE deleted=false) t '
                        . 'ON t.id = iv.teil_id WHERE iv.vorfall = "notfound" AND iv.import_id=' . $import['id']);
                if ($sqlres_errors->num_rows < 1) {
                    $this->ctb->tpl->assign('ERRORS', 'keine');
                } else {
                    $errorlinks = array();
                    while ($errors = $sqlres_errors->fetch_assoc()) {
                        $errorlinks[] = "<a href='?=$errors[id]' class='text-danger' data-toggle='tooltip' data-placement='bottom' title='$errors[bezeichnung]'>$errors[nummer]</a>";
                    }
                    $this->ctb->tpl->assign('ERRORS', implode(', ', $errorlinks));
                }


                $this->ctb->tpl->parse('TABLEROWS', '.');
            }
        }


    }
}
```

Feel free to ask questions if something is not clear.

Comment: I did not know that the use of capital and small letters was having an impact, so MY BAD. It works now ;)

Answer (score 1):

You have not quoted the name of the index on the associative array, just add quotes (simple or doubles).

```
$this->ctb->tpl->assign('DATUMZEIT', date('d.m.Y H:i:s', strtotime($import[importDate /* not quoted */])).' Uhr');
$this->ctb->tpl->assign('DATUMZEIT', date('d.m.Y H:i:s', strtotime($import['importDate'])).' Uhr');
```

Comment: Sorry, i had it with quotes in my code but it still was not working, as you can see 'exportFileModDate' does not give the right output aswell

Answer (score 1):

Your date format should be $import['importDate'] 
you currently using $import[importDate] that's why this value return 0 and date function convert date 01.01.1970 01:00:00 Uhr

Solution

$this->ctb->tpl->assign('DATUMZEIT', date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($import['importDate'])).' Uhr');

```
$sqlres = $this->ctb->sql->query('SELECT * FROM ' . $this->ctb->config->dbprefix . 'ausschuss_sap_import WHERE import="prices" ORDER BY importDate DESC');
    if ($sqlres->num_rows < 1) {
        $this->ctb->tpl->assign('TABLEROWS', '<tr><td colspan="2" class="text-center">bisher wurden keine Preise importiert</td></tr>');
    } else {
        $i = 0;
        while ($import = $sqlres->fetch_assoc()) {
            $i++;
            $this->ctb->tpl->assign('ROWCLASS', ($i == 1 && $importReturn == "success") ? 'success' : '');
            ** THATS WHERE I TRY TO GET MY IMPORTDATE OUT OF MY DATABASE **
           $this->ctb->tpl->assign('DATUMZEIT', date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($import['importDate'])).' Uhr');
            $this->ctb->tpl->assign('FILEDATE', date('d.m.Y H:i:s', strtotime($import['exportFileModDate'])).' Uhr');


            $sqlres_changes = $this->ctb->sql->query('SELECT t.id, t.nummer, t.bezeichnung '
                    . 'FROM ' . $this->ctb->config->dbprefix . 'ausschuss_sap_import_vorfall iv '
                    . 'LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM ' . $this->ctb->config->dbprefix . 'ausschuss_teile WHERE deleted=false) t '
                    . 'ON t.id = iv.teil_id WHERE iv.vorfall = "change" AND iv.import_id=' . $import['id']);
            if ($sqlres_changes->num_rows < 1) {
                $this->ctb->tpl->assign('CHANGES', 'keine');
            } else {
                $changelinks = array();
                while ($changes = $sqlres_changes->fetch_assoc()) {
                    $changelinks[] = "<a href='?module=ausschuss&action=editdata&table=preis&teil=$changes[id]' data-toggle='tooltip' data-placement='bottom' title='$changes[bezeichnung]'>$changes[nummer]</a>";
                }
                $this->ctb->tpl->assign('CHANGES', implode(', ', $changelinks));
            }


            $sqlres_errors = $this->ctb->sql->query('SELECT t.id, t.nummer, t.bezeichnung '
                    . 'FROM ' . $this->ctb->config->dbprefix . 'ausschuss_sap_import_vorfall iv '
                    . 'LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM ' . $this->ctb->config->dbprefix . 'ausschuss_teile WHERE deleted=false) t '
                    . 'ON t.id = iv.teil_id WHERE iv.vorfall = "notfound" AND iv.import_id=' . $import['id']);
            if ($sqlres_errors->num_rows < 1) {
                $this->ctb->tpl->assign('ERRORS', 'keine');
            } else {
                $errorlinks = array();
                while ($errors = $sqlres_errors->fetch_assoc()) {
                    $errorlinks[] = "<a href='?module=ausschuss&action=editdata&table=preis&teil=$errors[id]' class='text-danger' data-toggle='tooltip' data-placement='bottom' title='$errors[bezeichnung]'>$errors[nummer]</a>";
                }
                $this->ctb->tpl->assign('ERRORS', implode(', ', $errorlinks));
            }


            $this->ctb->tpl->parse('TABLEROWS', '.ausschuss_importPriceTableRow');
        }
    }



    $this->ctb->tpl->parse("AUSSCHUSSMAINPAGE", "ausschuss_importPriceSettings");
    $this->buildPage("settings");
}
```

}

Comment: Sorry, i had it with quotes in my code but it still was not working, as you can see 'exportFileModDate' does not give the right output aswell.

Comment: can you please give me print_r($import); outputs then i can understand what's the issue